# Itertools.combinations() on a Generator - Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, generator, combinations

Let's say I have a generator that produces some random number on each call. I want the combinations of these numbers in 2's.

```
def generate():
    while True: # Note this is not actually infinite, just an example
        yield random(1,10)

for combos in iter.combinations(generate(),2):
    #DO AN OPERATION WITH A COMBINATION
    #HOW DO I MULTI-THREAD THIS?
```

But my generator is going to yield a total number 'n' which is 24000+ numbers. So I need to process the combinations as they are made instead of storing in a list(memory).

I also need to multithread this operation by dividing the combinations among at least 4 threads.

I thought of doing this round robin, i.e. Assign 4 queues and each thread being responsible for 1 queue.

Do you guys have any other recommendations? I need the script to finish executing as soon as possible.

### EDIT:

Ok, I just wrote both versions of this program (list based, generator based).

And My list based version is actually taking less RAM. How is this possible?

### EDIT 2:

It was because I tried to plot points using pyplot point by point. This caused the graph to be re-rendered on every call.